# C++: Vector of Derived Objects with Polymorphic Members

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, polymorphism, class-template

Problem: I want to create a vector of parameters whose values are polymorphic. Each parameter has a name, a value, and set/get methods for value, which are also polymorphic.

Suppose I have the following base class:

```
class ParamBase
{
protected:
    std::string name;
};
```

and the following derived class template:

```
template<class T>
class Parameter : public ParamBase
{
public:
    T get_value() { return this->value; }
    T set_value(T val) { this->value = val; }
protected:
    T value;
}
```

As mentioned above, I want to have an array of Parameters whose values have different types. I know I can make an vector of ParamBase pointers doing something like this:

```
std::vector<ParamBase*> param_list = { { new Parameter<int> }, 
                                       { new Parameter<double> } }
```

Problem is, when I call *get/set_value* for an element of this vector, the compiler complains that *ParamBase* does not have a *get/set_value* method, which makes sense.

So my first instinct is to add a polymorphic virtual function, like this:

```
template<typename T>
virtual T get_value() = 0;
virtual T set_value() = 0;
```

But because virtual functions do stuff at run time (I think?), and templates do stuff at compile time (I think?), or for some other reason, this isn't allowed.

All that is to say... how can I get around this, if at all? I read something about using dynamic_cast, but it didn't seem to work for me (either that, or I did it wrong).

The only workaround I can think of is making separate classes for each type, and also writing separate virtual functions for each type - but I run into the problem of indistinguishable getters in the base class there.

Comment: Suppose it were possible, what do you expect the type of `param_list[0].get()` to be in general for an unknown list? And how can the compiler deduce that at compile time? Because C++ is statically typed.

Comment: Are you aware of `std::variant` and `std::any`?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you do this `param_list[0] = new Parameter<int>; param_list[0]->set_value("hello");`?

Comment: @Quimby I guess I'd expect it to use get_value() for whatever derived class ```param_list[0]``` belongs to. But that's not how it works, apparently

Comment: But that type would only be known at runtime, yet there C++ type system is compile time construct.

Comment: @RandyPrice *I want to create a vector of parameters whose values are polymorphic.* -- What is the actual high-level concept you are trying to implement?  Obviously your approach is not the right one for whatever that high-level goal is that you're trying to achieve.  If you give more information, there are probably existing codebases that do what you want or similar where you could get ideas from.

Comment: @RandyPrice You would need to type-cast the `ParamBase*` pointer in order to access members that only exist in derived classes, eg: `param_list[0] = new Parameter<int>; static_cast<Parameter<int>*>(param_list[0])->set_value(12345);` If you don't know what type is stored in a given array element, you will have to query it dynamically, such as with `dynamic_cast`, or by adding a type ID member to each object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why not `dynamic_cast<>`?

Comment: @sweenish `dynamic_cast` certainly works, it just has overhead since it is an RTTI query at runtime. Sometimes the overhead is either unnecessary or unwanted. There are simpler alternatives, when feasible to use them.

Comment: I'd use visitor pattern.  Using std::variant is also probably a good idea.